# Recording issue with Color Effect MONO on Nexus 5

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record video in monochrome effect and set `parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO)`

and effect appears, but when i start my Mediarecorder `mediaRecorder.start();`this effect disappears and preview and recorded video become colorful (without any effects). And i saw it only on Nexus 5 device, other devices (like Samsung Galaxy S6 or Xiomi Redmi 2 ) work properly.

Please, help if you know how this problem can be solved.

P.S. A have already tried a Camera2 and it also works, but not on the Nexus 5.

`builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_MONO);`

P.S.S. I also saw that  [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) react the same way. But some other cameras record without problems.